# The link between Kaiser Wilhelm I. and the city of Bonn

Tags: war, germany, imperial-germany, imperialism

To be more specific, I need to know the link between Kaiser Wilhelm I. and Bonn. Why was the monument placed there? Was it because of his glory or where other factors taking place?

Comment: I don't know _why_ it was erected (perhaps to curry favour with the Emperor?), but according to [this page](http://vanderkrogt.net/statues/object.php?record=denw450&webpage=ST) it was sculpted by Harro Magnussen and erected in 1906. After being damaged in the war, it was demolished and stored in a building yard from 1945. In 1988/89 it was restored and installed on a new base in the beer garden at the Kaiserplatz.

Comment: Related to [this piece](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fde.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FKaiser-Wilhelm-Denkmal_%28Venusberg%29&edit-text=&act=url) maybe? (Side note: it's fascinating how good Google translate has become of late. If any Googler involved in it reads this: great work!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is entirely normal for cities in empires to erect monuments to emperors. The exact practices vary between countries, but there seem to have been [at least 425 to Wilhelm I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_William_monuments) erected between his death in 1888 and 1918. It was unusual in Prussia to build monuments to living royals, even before the creation of the empire, so there were few before his death.

A more meaningful question would be "Who decided to put up this monument to him in Bonn?" That was likely just a group of patriotic local citizens who could raise the money, and obtain the agreement of the city's authorities and permission from the then-current Kaiser, Wilhelm II.